# Update input value depending on select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to update some `input` value depending on the selected option from a `select`.

Here is what I want to achieve :

I have a page that displays details of a domain name. I have a form with `input` and `select` which allows the price to be changed. The `input` contains the current domain name price and allows user to put a new price in, however the user don't have to do it and instead can use the `select` which have 3 options with 3 different currencies and once one is selected it should change the value of the new price `input` based on default price of given currency from the database.

Then it gets a little more complicated, because the script needs to know the TLD to lookup at the Database in order to find the correct price. I guess I need to pass it as a parameter somewhere...

The code itself works perfectly fine when submitted, and it applies the new price when different currency has been selected, but I can only see it after submitting, something I want to avoid.

I'm not sure how to do it. Should I use jQuery itself or jQuery AJAX or JS ? I'm pretty new to all of this async stuff and don't know where to start, really.

Comment: and we don't know where to help if you don't provide any code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do that javascript is fine. You need to learn about events. Events are triggered **when a specified action takes place**. In your case you want it to trigger when you **change the value of a select**. hence you will need to use the **onchange event**.

I created a really basic example sinc eyou didn't provide any code. Which you should be able to decipher to do what you want.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEventsToHTML(){
    var cars = document.getElementById('cars');
    cars.onchange = changeHandler;
    function changeHandler(){
        alert("You changed to "+this.value);
    }
}
window.onload = addEventsToHTML;
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <select id="cars">
      <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="MG">MG</option>
      <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
    </select>
```

Check out the [LIVE DEMO HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/GCqRR/)