# Select Country and country code?

Tags: php, html

I need a help in this issue. I am selecting a country in drop down and in the phone text column the country code should come when we select it. This is my code.

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="" Selected>Country...</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <optgroup label="Other countries">
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<label for="phone"style="width:100%;margin-bottom:20px;">
    <span style="color:#000;">Phone Number</span> <span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span>
    <br>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" required="" type="number">
</label>
```

And my Client need the country name to be shown to them, so in the option value I have given the country name. Here in my option value there is only the Country names has values not the country code. Should I place the country code some where else? Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update input value depending on select option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504473/update-input-value-depending-on-select-option)

Comment: Can you give me an example how to write in javascript..?

Comment: Please follow the link above. The accepted answer there has a solution. You would have to change `alert` to a function that updates the input's value, but the rest of the logic is exactly the same.

Comment: @Ritesh you should go with any jquery plugin like http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html take a demo here you will get solve your problem

Comment: @Ritesh also get more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882944/jquery-international-telephone-number-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code to get Country Code:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="" Selected>Country...</option>
<option value="+91">India</option>
<option value="+92">USA</option>
<optgroup label="Other countries">
    <option value="+93">Algeria</option>
    <option value="+91">Andorra</option>
    <option value="+95">Angola</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<label for="phone"style="width:100%;margin-bottom:20px;"><span 
style="color:#000;">Phone Number</span> <span style="color:#FF0000;">*
</span><br>
<input id="phone" name="phone" required="" type="number"></label>
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery("#counrty").change(function(){
   id=$(this).val();
   txt_str="id="+id;
   jQuery.get(get_country_code.php', txt_str,function(result){  
      jQuery("#phone").val(result);
   });
});
```

**In the get_country_code.php code has below code:**

```
<?php 
 include('connect.php');//database connection file

    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $query = $db->query("SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE country_id =".$id);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $counryCode = $row['country_code'];

    echo $counryCode; die;
?>
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: When we do this in database it will store has the country code but not the name of the country right? My client should also have the country name to be stored.

Comment: Than you need to run the Ajax and get the value from database and show the country code.

Comment: @Ritesh, see the updated answer. Change the fields and table name according to your database.